# What is the "Service Name" and "Display Name" for SQL Server Notification Services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the "Service Name" and "Display Name" for SQL Server Notification Services?  I need to check for it, but would rather not install it on a server just to get the names.

Thanks!

Comment: So you will code it w/o ever testing it?

Comment: (Sigh) It's a report.  I just need to know if the service is on any of our servers.